# Problems with disk partitions?

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, gparted

I use Ubuntu 12.04 alongside with Windows. Now I want to resize my Home Drive(i.e. /dev/sda7). When I try to move my NTFS partitions GParted(ver: 0.11.0) says that "Can't have overlapping partitions". Please help me.

Comment: This means that the partition you are moving is going to overlap with another partition. What you can do is shrink that partition (if there are space left) then try to move it again, make sure that there is enough unallocated space to where you'll move the partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your aim is to resize your disk partition all you have to do is follow the instructions given on the page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk. That's if you installed Ubuntu by running wubi.exe. If this isn't the case I'll let someone else answer your question.

Comment: You're very welcome. I had the same problem -- I know a lack of information can be frustrating.